# "mimic like a _____ (animal or something else)"?

Tags: idiom-requests

In my mother tongue we use ***monkey*** to describe a person who imitates or mimics a certain behaviour much like a *copycat* in English. I am surprised that the same image is not used in English, and even more surprised a cat was used to express this meaning. I don't see how a cat imitates things, it is actually known to be a rather self-willed animal that knows how to get what it wants, so to say. Probably that's why you have to add "copy" at the beginning, whereas ***monkey*** has the meaning of imitation inherent in it, a bit like ***parrot*** (with the difference that "parrot" refers to imitating words somebody said or the way they speak.)

So if I see someone imitating me, I can say in my mother tongue:

> Don't be a monkey! (Which in English would be ***Don't be a copycat***)

Are there any idioms or words that would express the meaning of imitating someone's gesture or behaviour? It can include the name of an animal or not. The sentence could look something like the one I gave already:

> Don't (be (such) a) ____ !

or

> What are you? A ____ ?

Note that my sentences are similar to what I would say in my mother tongue. However, the English idiom might have a different structure, so other ways of saying this would be acceptable.

Comment: Monkey: verb (used with object): 
to imitate; ape; mimic.
to mock. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/monkey

Comment: Also [**ape**](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/ape). (Look up the synonyms of *imitator, copycat* etc.)

Comment: @user66974: Yes, I was aware of the verb, but I am looking for an idiom containing a noun rather. That noun would be commonly known for imitating others.

Comment: “Stop mocking me” is fairly idiomatic. Can’t think  of an expression with an animal as a noun rather than  a verb.

Comment: I don't think there's an idiom, and DIY contrivances such as 'mimic like an ape / parrot / mimic octopus' sound unnatural.

Comment: I suspect that _copycat_ is from childish alliteration rather than any suggestion that cats imitate others.

Comment: @KateBunting Perhaps, but cats do imitate one another, especially kittens.